# Mounted PATH Dependent import works through CLI, not through script

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, nfs

I have a python module called `user_module`, which resides in a mounted network location.

In a script I'm using, I need to import that module - but due to NFS issues, sometimes this path isn't available until we actually change directory to the relevant one and\or restarting autofs service.

In order to reproduce the issue and try to WA it - I've manually stopped autofs service, and tried to run my script with my WA - (probably not the most elegant one though):

```
import os
import sys
from subprocess import call

PATH="/some/network/path"
sys.path.append(PATH)

try:
    os.chdir(PATH)
    import user_module
except:
    print "Unable to load user_module, trying to restart autofs service"
    call(['service', 'autofs', 'restart'])
    os.chdir(PATH)
    import user_module         # Throws Import error!
```

But, I still get import error due to path unavabilable.

Now this is what I find weird - On the same machine, I've tried executing the same operations as in my script, with intentionally pre stopping autofs service, and it works perfect -

```
[root@machine]: service autofs stop     # To reproduce the import error
[root@machine]: python

>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> from subprocess import call

>>> PATH="/some/network/path"
>>> sys.path.append(PATH)

>>> os.chdir(PATH)
######################################################################
################## exception of no such file or directory ############
######################################################################

>>> call(['service', 'autofs', 'restart'])
>>> os.chdir(PATH)             # No exception now after restarting the service
>>> import user_module         # NO Import error here
```

Can someone shed some light on the situation
and explain to me why same methodology works through python CLI, but through a script?

What is it that I don't know or what is it that I'm missing here?
Also - How to overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: print `sys.path`. and see whether it's added. Also, I don't think you need to change the directory before importing

Comment: Thanks , but the path indeed was added to `sys.path`. I've already tried that direction I'm afraid. The `chdir` is due to mounts issue - some mounts are triggered only by changing directory to them, as I've mentioned in the post

Comment: Is the current directory changing after `chdir` command? @Adiel

Comment: Yes, to the desired PATH @yklsga

Comment: Can you provide an example value PATH in the above code?

Comment: Yes of course - PATH="/auto/sdk/libs/tools" @yklsga